# Get itertools object by index, similar to how you get in list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

Are there any quick ways that I can easily derive the index from an `itertools.izip object`, similar to how you derive from a `list`?

I am trying to compare 2 values, one from a list, the other from the itertools object. While I can use `enumerate` on the object to grab the value, it seems that I will need to iterate all the values within the said object before doing so.

```
# if iterating from a list
list_values = [(1, 'a', 'john'), (2, 'b', 'jack'), (3, 'c', 'jill')]
print list_values[1] # returns me (2, 'b', 'jack')

# if trying to do the same as above but towards an itertools objext
iter_values = itertools.izip([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['john', 'jack', 'jill'])
print iter_values[1] # Errors-out
```

Comment: `izip` returns some kind of iterator, no? Also I’m curious, may I ask why you’re using Python 2?

Comment: Yes, because itertools objects aren't indexable. If you want to index it, then materialize it in a list. You can't have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: An iterator is an intentionally limited interface. The only thing an iterator knows how to do is return the *next* item (or raise `StopIteration` if there is no `next` item). But this limitation makes them broadly applicable. You can iterate over a list (in which case the iterator keeps track of the current index and increments it each time `next` is use), or you can iterate over something that computes the next element (or raises `StopIteration`) on demand. Such an iterator wouldn't what, if anything, exists at an arbitrary location.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't index an iterator. That's the trade-off, you don't have to keep the object in memory, but you don't get random access and indexing. You can slice an iterator with `itertools.islice()` but it's not an indexing operation of course and consumes the iterator.